# Jupyter: `ipykernel_launcher.py: error: the following arguments are required: --config` when opening notebook in project directory

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I am trying to create and run a jupyter notebook (`jupyter notebook --port xxxx`) in the directory of a project I am working on to do some debugging. When I try to run it the notebook fails to connect to a kernel with the following error returned by the server repeatedly:

```
[I 17:29:24.011 NotebookApp] KernelRestarter: restarting kernel (5/5), new random ports
2022-01-28 17:29:24.789877: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49]
Successfully opened dynamic library libcudart.so.11.0
usage: ipykernel_launcher.py [-h] --config CONFIG [--results_dir RESULTS_DIR]
ipykernel_launcher.py: error: the following arguments are required: --config
```

This is an empty notebook where I am trying to execute the first cell, it happens irrespective of the code that this cell contains. On top of that I CAN RUN A NOTEBOOK IN ANY OTHER DIRECTORY FROM THE SAME SERVER which makes this extra strange!

It seems that jupyter implicitly runs some code during kernel start that reads whatever is in my project directory out of context and inevitably fails to run it. I want to run it in that very directory to test the module I am working on.

I tried deleting `.ipynb_checkpoints`, restarting the server and recreating the notebook from scratch, but that didn't help.

Here is a selected `pip list` of the modules I have installed in my conda environment. Python version == 3.7.0

```
Package                 Version
----------------------- ---------
importlib-metadata      4.10.1
importlib-resources     5.4.0
ipykernel               6.7.0
ipython                 7.31.1
ipython-genutils        0.2.0
ipywidgets              7.6.5
jupyter                 1.0.0
jupyter-client          7.1.2
jupyter-console         6.4.0
jupyter-core            4.9.1
jupyterlab-pygments     0.1.2
jupyterlab-widgets      1.0.2
Keras-Preprocessing     1.1.2
matplotlib              3.5.1
matplotlib-inline       0.1.3
nbclient                0.5.10
nbconvert               6.4.1
nbformat                5.1.3
notebook                6.4.8
numpy                   1.19.5
pandas                  1.1.5
scipy                   1.7.3
tensorboard             2.8.0
tensorboard-data-server 0.6.1
tensorboard-plugin-wit  1.8.1
tensorflow-estimator    2.4.0
tensorflow-gpu          2.4.0
typing                  3.7.4.3
typing_extensions       4.0.1
```

Edit: This file is contained in the same directory as the notebook I am trying to run:

```
import argparse

from myModule.training import main

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('--config', type=str, required=True)
parser.add_argument('--results_dir', type=str, default='results_training')

args = parser.parse_args()
config = args.config
results_dir = args.results_dir

hist = main(config, results_dir)
```

Comment: Do you recognize anything in that usage line?  usage: `ipykernel_launcher.py [-h] --config CONFIG [--results_dir RESULTS_DIR]`.  Some commandline parser is expecting a `--config` argument, and also allows a `--results_dir`.  That's not the main `jupyter` usage.  I wonder if you are importing something that should be run as a script rather than a notebook.

Comment: I added a file called `train.py` that is in the same directory as the notebook. It does expect those arguments from the parser. However, do note that I am not actually importing or running it in any way from the notebook. The notebook can contain sth as simple as `import os` and trigger the above error in the jupyter server.

Comment: I don't know how or why that's being imported, but it does look like this is the parser that raising the error.  All a notebook sees in `sys.argv` is the `json` file used for interaction with the kernel.  To prevent a script from running `argparse` on import, it's recommended to put that code in a `if __name__ == '__main__': block.

Comment: So it turned out be another file in same directory as the notebook called `profile.py` that also had the same `argeparse` and was causing the error. ``if name == 'main'` wouldn't help it, cause it still tried running it and expected some attributes that obviously didn't exist. Only renaming `profile.py` to anything else resolved it.